# Eclipse cannot see generated classes

Tags: java, class, generated

I have a problem with seeing generated classes in eclipse. It is because generated classes in target folder which are generated during build, have the same package as existing package in the project where some java classes made by myself are . I want to keep generated class in target folder but eclipse cannot see the class as it does not find it in target because of the same package. Is there anything that I can do in settings to make eclipse see the class ?

Comment: refresh and do clean build. It should solve the issue!

Comment: I tried all these common things as cleaning, updating maven project imports etc.

Comment: had you already check default output folder path from project build path?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to refresh eclipse project. When you make any change (add or remove files/classes or change in file) in project outside the eclipse. You will need to refresh the eclipse project.

Right click on the project and click on the refresh in context menu

Comment: it does not work, to clarify it, imgaine it is the same thing as when you are makking unit tests class. They have the same package but the tested class is in src/main/java and the uni test is in src/test/java. I have one class in src/main/java.....package structure and generated class in target/....package structure (the same as in the first class) and the generated class must be visible from the first class. I cannot use import as I cannot import the same package. My colleagues have IntelliJ and they have no problems, but eclipse cant see the generated classes

Comment: it seems your generated class in not on classpath of eclipse project. Right click on the project and select project properties and verify that your generated class is included in **Java build path**